# Como hacer para que salga toda la informacion completa en un JTable

Tags: java, eclipse, java-swing

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber como hacer para que salga toda la inforamación completa en un JTable que creé dentro de un JScrollPane.
La cabecera lo creé con el código de DefaultTableModel.
Gracias.

```java
DefaultTableModel mMedico=new DefaultTableModel();
mMedico.addColumn("CÓDIGO");
mMedico.addColumn("NOMBRE");
mMedico.addColumn("APELLIDOS");
mMedico.addColumn("ESPECIALIDAD");
mMedico.addColumn("DNI");
mMedico.addColumn("FECHA DE NAC.");
mMedico.addColumn("EDAD");
mMedico.addColumn("SEXO");
mMedico.addColumn("DIRECCIÓN");
mMedico.addColumn("CORREO");
mMedico.addColumn("TELÉFONO");
mMedico.addColumn("FECHA DE REG.");
mMedico.addColumn("LOGIN");
mMedico.addColumn("CLAVE");
tblMedico.setModel(mMedico);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes construir el JTable con los siguientes argumentos:
Object[][] data: Arreglo bidimensional, cada elemento del arreglo es un renglón en la tabla y cada elemento del renglón es el valor de la columna respectiva.
Object[] columns: Etiquetas de las columnas. Si no se utiliza un String, se toma el valor de toString()

Answer (score 1):

Como dijo el usuario @Pedro Martin del Campo puedes pasar tanto el nombre de las columnas como sus respectivos datos en un arreglos de 1 y 2 dimensiones respectivamente como muestro en el codigo siguiente:

```
String nombresColumnas[] = {"CODIGO", "NOMBRE", "APELLIDOS"};

String datos[][] = {{"1", "roberto", "garcia"}, 
                    {"2", "maria", "perez"}, 
                    {"3","Jorge", "martinez"}};

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(datos, nombresColumnas);
jTable1.setModel(model);
```

Aclarar que en el ejemplo puse un table,jscrollpanel y boton que ejecuta el codigo anterior.
Saludos...

Answer (score 1):

Adicional a lo que te dicen @PedroMartindelCampo y @ReneGarnica, te muestro una forma poco convencional, pero que sin duda te ahorrará mucho trabajo a la hora de agregar items a una tabla, sobre todo si los traes de la base de datos.

**Requisitos**

- Añadir la librería [BeanBindings](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdesktop/beansbinding/1.2.1) al proyecto

Ahora podemos empezar.

**Crear una entidad**

Esta entidad representará a una tabla de la base de datos, de esta manera, sus propiedades son equivalentes a las columnas de la tabla. En este caso, tengo una tabla `Person` con las siguientes columnas:

- Nombre
- Apellido
- F_Nac
- DNI
- Direccion
- Telefono
- Email

La cual vamos a mapear a una entidad:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private Date birthDate;
    private String dni;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    public Person() {

    }

    public Person(String name, String lastname, Date birthDate,
                    String dni, String address, String phone,
                    String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Si te fijas, cada propiedad es el equivalente a una columna en la tabla.

**Crear los bindings para la tabla**

Ahora es necesario crear los bindings para la tabla. Esto lo hacemos con la librería antes mencionada.

```
private void initBindings() {
    group = new BindingGroup();
    JTableBinding binding = SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(
            UpdateStrategy.READ,
            people, // <- importante
            tblPeople
    );
    group.addBinding(binding);
    this.initEntityBindings(binding);
    group.bind();
}
```

Como se puede observar no es muy difícil. Tan solo creamos bindings para JTable, lo añadimos al grupo de bindings y aplicamos los bindings llamando a `BindingGroup#bind`. Sin embargo, fíjate en la línea:

```
people, // <- importante
```

La variable `people` será la que contenga la lista de personas cada vez que se hace una consulta a la base de datos. Es decir, no crearemos una `List<Person>` cada vez que hagamos una consulta; en su lugar, limpiaremos la lista y la volveremos a llenar con los resultados de la nueva consulta. Por ende, es recomendable que **la lista sea una constante** en algún sitio (de preferencia en el controlador del formulario):

```
private static final List<Person> people;
```

Además vemos que llamamos a `initEntityBindings`, que veremos a continuación.

**Asociar los bindings con propiedades**

Aquí lo que hacemos es simplemente asociar cada columna de la tabla bindeada a una propiedad de la entidad relacionada.

```
private void initEntityBindings(JTableBinding binding) {
  JTableBinding.ColumnBinding colBinding = binding.addColumnBinding(ELProperty.create("${name}"));
  colBinding.setColumnName("Nombre");
  colBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);

  colBinding = binding.addColumnBinding(ELProperty.create("${lastname}"));
  colBinding.setColumnName("Apellido");
  colBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);

  colBinding = binding.addColumnBinding(ELProperty.create("${birthDate}"));
  colBinding.setColumnName("F. Nac");
  colBinding.setColumnClass(Date.class);

  colBinding = binding.addColumnBinding(ELProperty.create("${dni}"));
  colBinding.setColumnName("DNI");
  colBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);

  colBinding = binding.addColumnBinding(ELProperty.create("${address}"));
  colBinding.setColumnName("Dirección");
  colBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);

  colBinding = binding.addColumnBinding(ELProperty.create("${phone}"));
  colBinding.setColumnName("Teléfono");
  colBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);

  colBinding = binding.addColumnBinding(ELProperty.create("${email}"));
  colBinding.setColumnName("Correo E.");
  colBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
}
```

Como vemos, por cada columna de la tabla, asociamos el nombre de la propiedad de la entidad y el tipo de dato. Simple.

#### Demostración

Para demostrar el funcionamiento solo debes hacer una consulta a la base de datos y mapear los resultados en tu entidad.

```
while(rs.next()) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName(rs.getString("nombre"));
    person.setLastname(rs.getString("apellido"));
    person.setBirthDate(rs.getDate("f_nac"));
    person.setDni(rs.getString("dni"));
    person.setAddress(rs.getString("direccion"));
    person.setPhone(rs.getString("telefono"));
    person.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
    PersonController.add(person);
}
```

Donde:

```
public class PersonController {

    public static final List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void add(Person p) { people.add(p); }

}
```

#### Resultado

[image]